# TamperMonkey: Modify Post Request Data Payload OR Change Response Body

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm still fairly new to user scripts/Javascript and have been looking for a way modify either the request data payload or change the returned response body of a post request. The site in question performs a XHR POST request (in curl)

```
curl 'https://somesite.com/endpoint' -X POST -H {various headers} --data-raw 'id=someid'
```

and usually returns a JSON response (36 character alphanumeric string, made up here) like

```
dg9gt8hs-ds8g-09ds-9dsf-ad8ygs70dsd0
```

Sometimes, the response can be a string that is checked against logic in a Javascript function. I've tried putting together a user script in TamperMonkey for this, but I'm not familiar enough with Javascript to get it working.

Ideally, this script would only be triggered for `https://somesite.com/endpoint`, and then randomly change `someid` before the POST request is sent OR modify the response body before being passed to the site's functions.

Is this possible with TamperMonkey? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can override the `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest` prototype before the website makes the request, or you can use `GM_webRequest()` to redirect/cancel that request.